How to Disable Display by command line?
In Ubuntu 22.04.4 Desktop Settings, Select Displays tab.
There are a list of displays. To disable/enable, toggle the button on the right side.
My question is: is it possible to disable/enable by command-line, script?
Where are the settings stored?
Thank you,
Tigerxy

Ubuntu Desktop is using wayland, not xorg/X11. I have seen /sys/class/drm/card1-Unknown-1, which I want to disable. It can be done through Settings/Display.
